# View edit suggestions/ pending edits in the mobile app

Tags: support, feature-request, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, editing-help

I'm using the Stack Exchange app. I can make edits to try to improve the quality of the site; The problem is, I never know how successful I am.

I can't view any of my pending edits or suggestions. I also can't view my edit history.

Is this possible in the mobile app? If not, can I recommend the feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current Mobile app ([version 1.0.83](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin&hl=en)) primarily targets to followup one's own posts. It allows a minimal support for Moderating features.

We can ask questions. We will get an alert for any answer or comment on our posts.

we can search questions, but results will be in ascending order only.

Only our top posts displayed in mobile app home page.

we can not access review queues

we can not see our list of votes, answers,questions,flags, edits & favorites

**The mobile app is far behind the features offered by traditional web browser view**. Which means, you can raise plenty of feature requests.

Comment: Actually, the API is the one with limitations/.

Comment: I don't have anything bad to say about the app and think the team does a great job overall. I was just offering some feedback to help them out

Comment: @user5680735, Even I prefer to have all the features in my mobile. You can create feature request. You have my up vote for sure ;)